# Accessing sequence of pairs in Schematron

Tags: xslt, schematron

I’m trying to build a Schematron to do very simple checks on paragraphs in HTML/XML documents for ”forbidden terms” and suggest a corresponding “preferred term”.

Example document snippet:

```
<p>A sentence containing the word Autobahn.</p>
<p>A sentence containing the word client.</p>
<p>A sentence containing the word newbie.</p>
```

My Schematron pattern looks like this:

```
<sch:pattern id="termChecker">
   <sch:let name="termPairs" value="(
      ('Autobahn', 'highway'),
      ('client', 'customer'),
      ('newbie', 'Beginner')
      )" />
   <sch:rule context="//p">
      <sch:let name="foundForbidden" value="(for $pair in $termPairs return if (contains(current(), $pair[1])) then $pair[1] else ())[1]" />
      <sch:let name="foundRecommended" value="(for $pair in $termPairs return if ($pair[1] = $foundForbidden) then $pair[2] else ())[1]" />
      <sch:report role="info" test="$foundForbidden">
         Warning: This text contains the forbidden word “<sch:value-of select='$foundForbidden'/>”.
         Alternative: “<sch:value-of select='$foundRecommended'/>”.
      </sch:report>
   </sch:rule>
</sch:pattern>
```

It ”almost” works, and I get three messages:

```
Info: This text contains the forbidden word “Autobahn”. Alternative: “”.
Info: This text contains the forbidden word “client”. Alternative: “”.
Info: This text contains the forbidden word “Newbie”. Alternative: “”.
```

So, it perfectly finds the ”forbidden terms” and returns them in the message (`<sch:value-of select='$foundForbidden'/>`).

However, the “preferred term” (`<sch:value-of select='$foundRecommended'/>`) always remains empty.

I have also tried several alternatives, like using indexed access:

```
<sch:value-of select="(for $i in 1 to count($termPairs) return if (contains(current(), $termPairs[$i][1])) then $termPairs[$i][2] else ())[1]"/>
```

or this:

```
<sch:value-of select="(for $pair in $termPairs return if (contains(current(), $pair[1])) then $pair[2] else ())[1]"/>
```

But I just can’t get it running.

I tried it in oXygen (23.1) with ISO Schematron configured to support XSLT2 (also tested XSLT3) and also tested Schematron 1.5 configured to support XSLT 2 (also tested XSLT 3.1).
I also tried it with ph-schematron with the ph-schematron-xslt module, but with the exact same result.
For some reason, the structure of $termPairs as a sequence of pairs and the way I’m accessing these pairs (`$pair[1]`, `$pair[2]`) is only working for `$pair[1]` but never for `$pair[2]`.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Sequences are always flat so you don't have pairs in there unless you switch to sequences of arrays or arrays of arrays or arrays of sequences (all of that would be XPath 3.1). You could also consider using a map.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: In XPath versions prior to 3.1, sequences are indeed flat, so my (('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')) would be interpreted as a flat sequence: ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'). However, I understood that in XPath 3.1 I can use more complex structures, such as arrays and maps, which allow for nested data like arrays of arrays or sequences of arrays. In XPath 3.1, it should be possible to create nested structures, which would be needed to represent pairs as I initially intended. However, even with XPath 3.1 support, it fails for me.

Comment: You can created nested structures like sequences of arrays, arrays of arrays, arrays of sequences but sequences itself remain flat so your attempt `( ('Autobahn', 'highway'),  ('client', 'customer'), ('newbie', 'Beginner') )` remains a flat sequence of six strings. See whether my answer helps or learn the array syntax `[['Autobahn', 'highway'], ['client', 'customer'], ['newbie', 'Beginner']]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a "flat" sequence but consider it to be structured as pairs then the following might do:

```
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" queryBinding="xslt3">
    <pattern>
           <let name="termPairs" 
                value="(
      ('Autobahn', 'highway'),
      ('client', 'customer'),
      ('newbie', 'Beginner')
      )" />
        <rule context="p">
            <let name="foundForbidden" value="$termPairs[position() mod 2 = 1][contains(current(), .)]"/>
            <report role="info"
                    test="exists($foundForbidden)">
                    Warning: This text "<value-of select="."/>" contains the forbidden words “<value-of select='$foundForbidden'/>”.
                    Alternatives: “<value-of select='for $pos in ($foundForbidden ! index-of($termPairs, .) + 1) return $termPairs[$pos]'/>”.
            </report>
        </rule>
    </pattern>
</schema>
```

A map as an alternative:

```
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" queryBinding="xslt3">
    <ns prefix="map" uri="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"/>
    <pattern>
           <let name="termPairs" 
                value="map {
                       'Autobahn' : 'highway',
                       'client' : 'customer',
                       'newbie' : 'Beginner'
                      }" />
        <rule context="p">
            <let name="foundForbidden" value="map:keys($termPairs)[contains(current(), .)]"/>
            <report role="info"
                    test="exists($foundForbidden)">
                    Warning: This text contains the forbidden words “<value-of select='$foundForbidden'/>”.
                    Alternatives: “<value-of select='$termPairs?($foundForbidden)'/>”.
            </report>
        </rule>
    </pattern>
</schema>
```

An array of arrays (of two items, each pair) would be

```
<pattern>
       <let name="termPairs" 
            value="[['Autobahn', 'highway'], ['client', 'customer'], ['newbie', 'Beginner']]" />
    <rule context="p">
        <let name="foundForbidden" value="$termPairs?*[contains(current(), ?1)]"/>
        <report role="info"
                test="exists($foundForbidden)">
                Warning: This text contains the forbidden words “<value-of select='$foundForbidden?1'/>”.
                Alternatives: “<value-of select='$foundForbidden?2'/>”.
        </report>
    </rule>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much, Martin! I went for the map approach, and it works like a charm now. In case someone else needs it as well: It also works with queryBinding="xslt2" and with ph-schematron with the ph-schematron-xslt module.